# sending mail to multiple recipent from android application

Tags: android

Hi i am a newbie trying to send mails to multiple recipents from my android application but unsuccessfull.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        ////i.setType("text/plain");

        //get and prepare recp list
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("filename", 0);

        String v1 = sp.getString( "addr1","Incorrect Key");
        String v2 = sp.getString( "addr2","Incorrect Key");
        String v3 = sp.getString( "addr3","Incorrect Key");
        String v4 = sp.getString( "addr4","Incorrect Key");
        String s1 = v1.concat(",").concat(v2).concat(",").concat(v3).concat(",").concat(v4);            

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{s1});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "On Sick Leave.");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am not feeling well so will be on Illness Leave today.");
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "vishesh.ab@gmail.com" });
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Insta_Msg.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        }
```

it is not the issue with shared preference as i check in debugger i get all the 4 recipents mail ids correct .

when i click send mail goes to only 1 email id.

Thanks in advance ,
Vishesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate the e-mail addresses to a string, just build the String array with the available e-mail addresses

```
 i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{v1,v2,v3,v4});
```

Comment: Hi Alex i tried giving the way you mentioned but still mail is sent only to single person.. Any other idea y it is not sending..?

Comment: Yes i have, I have edited my answer. Use android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL instead of Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL also use the "android.content.Intent." for the EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT just in case

Comment: Hi Alex i tried putting android.content.Intent for EXTRA_EMAIL , EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_TEXT but the mail is sent only to 2 mails ids not to 4...

Comment: In the e-mail composer window are you seeing all 4 e-mail addresses passed from the app ?

Comment: And if you tap on the "2 more" you should be able to see the other 2 e-mail address

Comment: Yes i am able to see all 4 mails ids if i click on 2 more.. but mail goes only to 2... If same mail id is entered more than once than mail doesn't go at all.

Comment: I think that is the e-mail client's problem and i'm not sure how you could fix it, maybe try other methods invoking the mail client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{s1,s2,s3,s4});
// Here s1,s2,s3 and s4 are your mail IDs


Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        ////i.setType("text/plain");

        //get and prepare recp list
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("filename", 0);

        String v1 = sp.getString( "addr1","Incorrect Key");
        String v2 = sp.getString( "addr2","Incorrect Key");
        String v3 = sp.getString( "addr3","Incorrect Key");
        String v4 = sp.getString( "addr4","Incorrect Key");
        String s1 = v1.concat(",").concat(v2).concat(",").concat(v3).concat(",").concat(v4);            

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{s1,s2,s3,s4});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "On Sick Leave.");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "I am not feeling well so will be on Illness Leave today.");
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "vishesh.ab@gmail.com" });
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Insta_Msg.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        }
```